# Telling XCOPY to copy hidden folders as well as hidden files

Tags: dos, xcopy

I'm trying to get XCOPY to copy an entire directory tree and all its files, however, one of the directory paths includes a hidden folder, and although you can use the /h parm to specify copying hidden files, this doesn't seem to apply to hidden folders.  I've been all over the docs for XCOPY and there doesn't seem to be one that deals with hidden folders.  But perhaps someone knows differently?

```
`xcopy c:\profiles c:\aprofiles /r /e /h /v /y
```

The above works fine except for the hidden *folders*.  I suppose that I could change the hidden folders to make them non-hidden, but there are a few hundred of them.

Comment: It's `/h`. So I don't know what the problem is... And here it works (Windows 7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @xanatos says, it copies hidden folders in Windows 7.

I couldn't get it to copy hidden folders in Windows 2003 Server, yes, even using the /h switch.  Hidden files, yes, but not hidden folders.

Weird.

Answer (score 5):

funny I was just trying to xcopy and had the same issue, i know this is 7 years late but it might help

using /h /s /e seems to copy hidden files and directorys correctly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding /s.  /e should be taking care of that, but doesn't appear to be doing so.  I just tested this with a /s and it gave me the hidden folders of a user's profile, as well as all the content of each.