# Copy all desktop.ini using xcopy

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy

I use this command in order to copy all .ini files (with recursion):
`xcopy c:\folder1\folder1A\*.ini c:\mybackup /sy` It doesn't copy any file.

There exist desktop.ini files (including comments) within folders and subfolders of `folder1A` that I want to get a copy of with recursion.

I have tried running CMD as administrator, but it tells `0 File(s) copied`. How could I get this to work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812037/telling-xcopy-to-copy-hidden-folders-as-well-as-hidden-files ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `/h` option:
`/H           Copies hidden and system files also.` ([more info](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/240268/copy-xcopy-and-move-overwrite-functionality-changes-in-windows))

This works:
`xcopy c:\folder1\folder1A\*.ini c:\mybackup /syh`

Thanks to [Marged](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354537/marged)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735963/copy-all-desktop-ini-using-xcopy#comment84471725_48735963) mentioning this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812037/telling-xcopy-to-copy-hidden-folders-as-well-as-hidden-files).